# Does app check check work with firebase phone auth?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm new to web development in general. started learning Javascript last year.

I created a website for testing. Before implementing app check, phone auth worked fine.

I'm using reCaptcha enterprise for app check.

I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: recaptchaVerifier.render is not a function

implementing app check:

```
const { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } = require("firebase/app-check");

const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(firebaseApp, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider('**********************************'),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true // Set to true to allow auto-refresh.
});
```

My javascript code for implementing phone auth:

```
$('#phone-method').click(function() {

 window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {}, auth);
 // Sign in with phone flow
})
```

Comment: Does this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there was a problem with enterprise but they have since fixed it:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6133

Answer (score 0):

Same problem to me, but this thread in Github help me:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6133

Here you have a nice sample inside.

It seems that appCheck only works great with ReCaptchaV3Provider. You will just have to change:

```
initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(*****),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
})
```

to:

```
initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(*****),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
})
```

And I recommend to change the way to initialize captcha, set to invisible like this:

```
 window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', 
 { 'size': 'invisible' },
 auth);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding! I was actually the 2nd commentor of that thread in git. At that time, both v3 and enterprise didn't work since I checked both. Good thing v3 works now. I've updated my site accordingly. Also, thanks for the rec on initializing captcha. I'm actually quite new to web dev and I do need all the help that I can get.